# campo de instancia no persiste

Tags: c#, constructor, instancias

En una clase, defino el campo

```
private SqlConnection cn;
```

y en el constructor le asigno valor:

```
 cn = new SqlConnection(Funcions.GetConnectionString(DB.Conexion, "COMUNES"));
```

Esta clase,se encarga de crear unos Triggers en una tabla Sqlserver:

```
 public void CreateVehiculos()
        {
            string query = $@"
                            CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CreateVehiculos]...";
            
            using(cn)
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                try
                {
                    if (!ExistsTrigger("CreateVehiculos"))
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    CLog.WriteLog(CLog.ObtenMetodoActual(),e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

public void UpdateVehiculos()
{
    string query = $@"CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateVehiculos]...";
    using (cn)
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        try
        {
            if (!ExistsTrigger("updateVehiculos"))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            CLog.WriteLog(CLog.ObtenMetodoActual(),e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

El caso, es que cuando instancio y uso esta clase:

```
TriggersSql trigger = new TriggersSql();
trigger.CreateVehiculos();
trigger.UpdateVehiculos();
```

En `trigger.CreateVehiculos();` El campo cn contiene la conexión asignada en el constructor de la clase y crea el trigger sin problemas,
pero cuando vuelvo a consumir esa instáncia en `trigger.UpdateVehiculos();` cn es null, ha perdido la conexión y no se el motivo.
Ya se que puedo asignarle valor en cada uno de los métodos y ancha es castilla, es curiosidad.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que comentas te está pasando porque usas `Using` el cual, al terminar siempre hace un `Dispose` del objeto que se está usando, por lo que te lo deja en `null` como bien indicas.

Esto puedes leerlo en la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Si quieres usar el `Using`, deberías crear la conexión cada vez que lo vas a usar:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
           Funcions.GetConnectionString(DB.Conexion, "COMUNES")))
{
    . . .
}
```

Si no, simplemente no tendrías que usarlo, y asegurarte de que la conexión se cierra cuando termines de usarla, aunque se recomienda usar siempre `Using` para no dejarte nada abierto y destruir el objeto después de usarlo.